# Using RX-Java for dependent actions and http requests

Tags: android, rx-java

I'm trying to use rx-java on Android to do few sequential http requests, each of which is dependent of the response of the former one.
This does not quite fit the map() / doFinall() model and so I'm not sure what would be the best way to do this without getting into "callback hell" as well as writing concise code.

More concretely:

1. do http GET "/x"
2. do http GET "/y" if (2) was successfully
3. do calculation on the result of GET /y

Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Answer (score 4):

I think flatMap is what you're looking for. For example, assuming you have the following methods:

```
Observable<Foo> getFoo();
Observable<Bar> getBar(Foo foo); //needs a Foo first
```

You could effectively chain them this way:

```
getFoo().flatMap(new Func1<Foo, Observable<Bar>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<Bar> call(Foo foo) {
        return getBar(foo);
    }
});
```

You could then perform some calculation with the final result Bar by subscribing to the resulting `Observable<Bar>` (full example shown for clarity):

```
getFoo().flatMap(new Func1<Foo, Observable<Bar>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<Bar> call(Foo foo) {
        return getBar(foo);
    }
}).subscribe(new Action1<Bar>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Bar bar) {
        //everything succeeded, so perform calculation to the Bar
    }
}, new Action1<Throwable>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Throwable throwable) {
        //handle an error that occurred anywhere in the chain      
    }
});
```

Note that an error anywhere in the process of getting the Foo or the Bar will be handled by the Action1 that we provide when subscribing to the Observable. It is, of course, painfully verbose because Java, but at least it avoids nesting Observables/callback hell.

Comment: Was thinking of something like [Promises](https://github.com/darylteo/rxjava-promises). This seems a little verbose... Was hoping for some shortcut

Comment: I didn't know of the existence of RxJava promises -- I think that's probably a better and clearer way. flatMap makes perfect sense when applied to a List<List<Foo>> but always (to me) seems a little weird when generalized to other monadic things. Especially in this case where each observable only contains one thing.